# Why would turning off a ceiling fan via a wall switch causes 3 seconds of TV signal loss?

Tags: electrical

Wall "A" has a switch that controls the light on the ceiling fan.
Wall "B" has an outlet used by TV and cable box.
Wall "C" has a switch that controls the light on the ceiling fan - alongside a switch controlling just the ceiling fan.

(There are other outlets in the room and, at least, two other rooms on this circuit but I haven't noticed any connection between those and this issue.)

When TV and ceiling fan are on, turning OFF the fan causes the TV to go black and silent for about three seconds before recovering. The TV's power indicator light stays on during the outage.

The house is 18 yrs. old. I've lived here 15 and this just started in the last 2-3 months.

If anyone recognizes the problem and can offer a remedy, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: How old is the television?

Comment: Does anything happen to the TV if you turn the LIGHT off?  And is your tv getting its signal with an antenna (OTA) or with a cable or satellite tv box?

Comment: Tv is 2 yrs. old.

Comment: Light switch has no effect ON or OFF.   Signal is via cable box.   It is HD TV.   Hope this added info helps. Thanks, in advance, for all your efforts!

Comment: It sounds like turning off the fan is generating EMI that is interfering with the TV/cable box.

Comment: Are you receiving an over the air signal like antenna, or a hardwired connection?

Comment: What happens to a light plugged into the outlet the TV uses?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the coils in the fan create flyback voltage that has nowhere to go so it radiates as EMF. Ensure that the fan is connected to ground to rule this out or fix the issue.